# pyPDF Unable to resolve IndirectObject getting pdf with empty pages

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I trying to read PDF file to do that i using following code:

```
from PyPDF3 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket(my_s3Bucket_on_AWS)
object = bucket.Object(my_s3_file_on_AWS)
tmp = tempfile2.NamedTemporaryFile()

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(tmp.name, "rb"), strict=False)
num_pages = inputpdf.getNumPages()
output = PdfFileWriter()
for i in range(num_pages):
    logger.info(f"Adding page --> {i}")
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i)) # Works fine until now
```

Works perfect for at least 10K of PDFs, until 1 PDF that is getting following error:

> UserWarning: Unable to resolve [IndirectObject: IndirectObject(7, 0)],
> returning NullObject instead [pdf.py:644]
>
> UserWarning: Unable to resolve [IndirectObject: IndirectObject(9, 0)],
> returning NullObject instead [pdf.py:644]
>
> UserWarning: Unable to resolve [IndirectObject: IndirectObject(10,
> 0)], returning NullObject instead [pdf.py:644]
>
> UserWarning: Unable to resolve [IndirectObject: IndirectObject(13,
> 0)], returning NullObject instead [pdf.py:644]
>
> UserWarning: Unable to resolve [IndirectObject: IndirectObject(16,
> 0)], returning NullObject instead [pdf.py:644]
>
> UserWarning: Unable to resolve [IndirectObject: IndirectObject(20,
> 0)], returning NullObject instead [pdf.py:644]
>
> UserWarning: Unable to resolve [IndirectObject: IndirectObject(24,
> 0)], returning NullObject instead [pdf.py:644]
>
> UserWarning: Unable to resolve [IndirectObject: IndirectObject(29,
> 0)], returning NullObject instead [pdf.py:644]

Any suggestion about how to fix this?

**Note:** The PDF i trying to read is not empty, it have data.

Comment: You could give a recent version of `PyPDF2` a try - I recently became the maintainer and merged many bugfixes :-) If the issue still appears, you can create a bugticket + share it here.

Comment: Thanks!! I solved using another library, but thanks for your suggestion I really apretiate!